# Create a new permanent table from all the data in 4 other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, create-table

I have 4 tables I created in SQL Server from 4 `.csv` files (4 calendar quarters of data) using its import wizard. They all have 12 columns with identical column names, in the same order, with the same respective data types, etc.

Now, I need to combine/merge all of the data in all of them into one permanent table. Once merged, the table will have about 4.7 million rows.

I thought the way to do it would be a `UNION` but I don't know how to turn the result of that into a permanent table.

So I created a new, empty table (called `Master`) with all the identical columns and data types of the original 4 tables. I figured I'd use all the data from those 4 table to populate the new table using `INSERT INTO`.

While I was able to create the new empty table, it's not appearing in the left navigation pane where the original 4 tables appear. Regardless, I can't figure out how to populate the new `Master` table with all the data from the 4 original tables anyway. I tried `INSERT INTO` but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this yourself in SQL:

```
select *
into all_data
from table1
union all
select *
from table2
union all
select *
from table3
union all
select *
from table4;
```

The use of `select *` assumes that the tables have the same columns defined in the same order.  If not, you should just list the columns by name.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. So what is the name of the new table? Will it appear in the left navigation pane with the original tables?

Comment: You probably need to refresh to see it.

Comment: Bummer, been refreshing a lot, none of the tables I create using CREATE TABLE show up there.

Comment: I'm trying to delete the one I made this morning, called Master but it says it doesn't exist, yet when I do a SELECT * FROM Master, all the data's there.

Comment: Mitch, why not name it Master, is that a reserved word?

Comment: 'master' is one of SQL Server's system databases.